# Writing an array to a file using C

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a model of Unix v6 File system. I have tried to first allocate the available free blocks by writing it to the file and then reading the same when need. I am having a free array of 100 blocks, so when the number of free blocks goes beyond hundred, the present free array will be written to the memory block in free[0] and the new free block will be assigned to free[0]. The following is the sample code that I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void splitCommand(char**,char*, char*);
unsigned short freeArr[100];
unsigned short nfree=1,fd;
int main()
{

    fd = open("v6", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IREAD | S_IEXEC | S_IWRITE);
    freeArr[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 28; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        addFreeBlock(i);
    }

    unsigned short free1=0  ;
    lseek(fd, 3127 * 512, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &(nfree), sizeof(unsigned short));
    printf("%d\n",nfree);
    for(int i=0; i<nfree; i++)
    {
        read(fd, &free1, sizeof(unsigned short));
        printf("%d\n",free1);
    }
}

void addFreeBlock(int block_no)
{
    if(block_no==3127)
    {
        int a=0;
    }

    if (nfree == 100)
    {
        lseek(fd, block_no * 512, SEEK_SET);
        write(fd, &(nfree), sizeof(unsigned short)); // copy nfree into free array
        write(fd, freeArr, 200);// copy free array
        nfree=0;
    }
    freeArr[nfree] = block_no;
    nfree++;
}
```

Consider we have 5000 blocks in total. Each block is 512 bytes long. I am using the first 27 blocks for other purposes and so I am writing the blocks from 28 to 5000.

Now after writing all the blocks, I tried reading the blocks stored at random location. When I tried reading the blocks stored at 3027, I am able to read the 100 blocks numbered from 2927,2928,2929,....,3026. But when I read  the blocks stored at 3127, I am able to read only the blocks from 3027, 3028, 3029,....,3081. The remaining is just random. I also tried at some other positions. It works for some of them.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: `nfree` is `int` and you use `sizeof(unsigned short)` use `sizeof(nfree)` instead.

Comment: Is the cat sat on the space bar? Anyway why not check the return value from `open`?

Comment: @EdHeal, from `open` and `read` and `write` ... all of them I think are important.

Comment: @iharob - I agree

Comment: What happens if you change the type of `nfree` to `unsigned short`?

Comment: Boys and girls - this code does not compile - see `read(fd, &free1, sizeof(unsigned short));` - Where is `free1` declared?

Comment: I changed everything to unsigned short (It is unsigned short in my original application) .. Still, it is not working... even now I get the same values as 3027, 3028, 3029,....,3081,6668,6668,6668...

Comment: Please post code that compiles

Comment: @EdHeal I am sorry.. I have edited it.. Now its good

Comment: It's not good. Please format it so it's readable. Also, WHY global variables, that just makes it harder to understand the code and debug. I have fixed your code guessing most of the things you want to achieve and it is working, but I REMOVED ALL GLOBAL VARIABLES BECAUSE THEY'RE NOT NEEDED. I will not post the code until I figure out WHY your code fails.

Comment: @iharob - Another case of the cat sat on the key board?

Comment: Oh, and there is no prototype for `addFreeBlock()` I suspect you are ignoring compiler warnings. If you are compiling without warnings, enable warnings with `-Wall`.

Comment: What is the point of this `if(block_no==3127)
    {
        int a=0;
    }
`

Comment: @iharob I know the code is not in good format.. I have copied this from my original application which is too big..  I am following all the above-said rules in my application. But anyways sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: @EdHeal the question explains that the OP skips first 27 bytes.

Comment: @EdHeal I have allocated the first 27 blocks for some other purposes.. so I am adding the blocks starting from 28

Comment: My mistake. Sorry

Comment: @iharob I used the global variables so that I can use them in the other methods. Please correct me if I am wrong... P.S In my original application these variables appear within a struct.

Comment: 1. Do not use global variables. Period.2. Does this code compile?

Comment: You are completely wrong. Check my answer. And they are not *methods*, in c there are only **functions**.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not really an answer but I cannot write this in a comment. It does however answer the question somehow.

Your code works correctly, I tested with [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) and there are no errors, but you should think about it a lot.

There is no need for a single global variable in your code, you should only use a global variable when you **really** know there is no better solution, this is an improved version of your exact code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t add_free_block(int fd, int block_number, uint16_t *free_blocks, uint16_t free_block_count);

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t free_blocks[100];
    uint16_t free_block_count;
    int fd;

    fd = open("v6", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IREAD | S_IEXEC | S_IWRITE);
    if (fd == -1)
        return -1;
    free_blocks[0] = 0;

    free_block_count = 1;
    for (int i = 28; i < 5000; i++) {
        free_block_count = add_free_block(fd, i, free_blocks, free_block_count);
    }

    lseek(fd, 3127 * 512, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &free_block_count, sizeof(uint16_t));

    printf("%d\n", free_block_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < free_block_count; i++) {
        uint16_t block_number;        
        if (read(fd, &block_number, sizeof(uint16_t)) == sizeof(uint16_t)) {
            printf("%d\n", block_number);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

uint16_t 
add_free_block(int fd, int block_number, uint16_t *free_blocks, uint16_t free_block_count)
{
    if (free_block_count == 100) {
        lseek(fd, block_number * 512, SEEK_SET);

        write(fd, &free_block_count, sizeof(uint16_t));
        write(fd, free_blocks, free_block_count * sizeof(uint16_t));

        free_block_count = 0;
    }
    free_blocks[free_block_count] = block_number;

    return free_block_count + 1;
}
```

with *0* global variables (*also, minor but important I closed the file descriptor*).

You should also check other return values like `write()`, I didn't because I didn't want to do it all, I just wanted check what was wrong.

The real problem lies somewhere else in the rest of your program, not in this code. So please POST the real code and stop guessing what the problem is.

In general, these are my recommendations

1. DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES, unless you are *very*, *very* sure you MUST.
2. Add the function prototype.
3. DO NOT IGNORE compiler warnings.
4. ALWAYS check the return value of a function that does return, if you don't know that it does return, then 5.
5. READ carefully all the documentation for every function you use.

Comment: The real code is more than 1000 lines.. So I thought of not complicating the question. Also, I executed your code using codeblocks in windows. I got the same output 3027, 3028, 3029,....,3081,... random numbers. Can you please post your output.

Comment: Then use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) yourself and check your code for erros. And my output os `100 3027 3028 ... 3126`.

Comment: You are on windows, you don't have valgrind. How is codeblocks compiling this?

Comment: It is compiling and I got the above-mentioned output. Anyway Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tried running the same code in code::blocks on ubuntu. It is working as expected in it.  Do you have any idea about this change of behavior?

Comment: I have no idea, but that makes me hate Windows a little more.